# Using Cramer's rule to prove that a system has a unique solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, determinant

I came across this exercise:

*Use Cramer's rule to find the values of k for which the system of equations below has a unique solution:*

$$x - 2y + k = k + 4$$

$$(k-1)x + y + z = k-3$$

$$-kx + 2y - 2z = -10 $$

So my question is how is Cramer's rule relevant here? An obvious way to find the values of k for which the system has a solution would be finding the values of k for which the determinant of the coefficients matrix is $\neq 0$. Are the authors of the exercise expecting an answer along these lines?

U*sing Cramer's rule to find the solution of system we have:*

$x = \frac{D_x}{D}, y = \frac{D_y}{D}, z = \frac{D_z}{D}$

*In order for the above solution to exist, $D \neq 0$
etc. etc. etc.* and we find the values of k for which $D \neq 0$

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you are missing something.

It suffices to find out the values of $k$ for which the determinant of the coefficient matrix is not zero.

More precisely, one has the following equation to solve:
\begin{align*}
\det(A) & =
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & -2 & 0\\
k - 1 & 1 & 1\\
-k & 2 & -2
\end{vmatrix} \neq 0
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know how to solve the exercise. I just don't see how Cramer's rule is relevant

Comment: It depends on what you call Cramer's rule. By the context of the exercise, I suppose it is enough to determine the above-mentioned values of $k$ which do not vanish the determinant.

Comment: @VakiPitsi  See [Cramer's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule) and note that the pertinent denominator is not allowed to equal $(0)$.

Comment: Thank you both just as I suspected

Comment: @VakiPitsi you can upvote/choose my answer if you think it deserves.